On a ground rule double on a walk off play is there anyway that the hitter only gets one base.?
This scenario is Jurickson Profar hit a walk off ground rule, double but they’re only awarding him a single. I’m not sure why since the ball hit the crowd, and that immediately becomes a dead ball and he should be placed on second base on top of the fact that the ball hit the crowd before the runner scored how is it possible that he’s only being awarded a single? Mind you when a couple days prior the Phillies beat the Padres on the exact same play. Nick Ciano‘s hit a walkoff ground rule double and was awarded two bases. Only difference was I believe Ciano’s made it to second base and was mobbed there and never did, but the place should have been deemed dead anyway.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think the question is clear. Can it be more concise or better formatted? Sure. But it's clear what's being asked is why one ground rule walk-off scenario was awarded a single while another was awarded a double.

MLB.com states why:

one thing Profar didn’t do was touch second base for his free double,
given that the ball had bounced into the stands. He was credited
instead with a single.

